# finding highest value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, variables, if-statement, printing

Here is my array code:

```
int h = 0;
int i = 1;
while (h < a.length - 1){
    if (a[h] < a[i]){
        h++;
        i++;
    }
    if (a[h] > a[i]){
        a[i] = a[h];
        a[h] = a[i + 1];
    }
}
if (h == a.length - 1){
System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need the answer for a school assignment. I'm in my school's computer science class.

Comment: This is an opportunity for you to step through the code in a debugger.  You'll become an infinitely better programmer for it.  Are you using an IDE?  If not, download one right now - they're free

Comment: That is a really screwy way to find the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, i'm not sure what language are you using, but i would choose to use `for` loop instead of `while`

```
int h = 0;
int i = 0;
int v = null;
while (h < a.length - 1){
    if(v == null || v < a[i])
    {
        v = a[i];
        h = i;
    }
    i++;
}
if (v != null){
   System.out.println(v); //for value
   System.out.println(h); //highest index
   System.out.println(a[h]); //for value from array a
}﻿
```

Comment: How can you assign `null` to an `int` in Java?

Comment: You also said you prefer `for` over `while`, but used `while` anyway.

Comment: @HotLicks the question was not tagged as `java` so i was not sure what language he used.

Comment: @DennisMeng since he is new to programming i wanted to help him learn not to give him a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create this method

```
  public int max(int[] a) {
        int temp = a[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > temp) {
                temp = a[i];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

and in your main method

```
int[] a = new int[3];
        a[0]=2;
        a[1]=3;
        a[2]=54;
System.out.println("Highest value is "+ max(a));
```

Comment: fwiw, you could also just do `int[] a = {2,3,54};`

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = a[0];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > max) {
        max = a[i];
        index = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(a);
System.out.println(a[a.length - 1]);
```